# else block in if else block not being executed - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement

I'm making a call to any api to get a specific data and trying to do something with it.

In this case i'm checking if `myname` is present or not present. If `myname` in this instance is not present, it moves to the `catch` block and not logging `no Name` as specified in the `else` statement which is not the desired behavior. why is the `else` block not getting printed?

```
try {
  const res = await apiCall
  const myname : string = res.body?.myname

  if (myname.length > 0) {
    console.log('Name')
  } else {
    console.log('no Name')
  }

} catch (error:any) {
  console.log('error', error)
}
```

Comment: Because `undefined` doesn't have a `length` property so that will trigger an error.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Thought about that too. what would you differently ?

Comment: `if (myname?.length) {` which is same as `if(myname && myname.length) {`

Comment: Given the situation. `if(myname)` should be enough. As based on https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp

Comment: it keeps jumping to the catch block which is weird and super annoying. i'm trying to handle a situation where the name is not present and it seems pretty straightforward but i'm quite surprised at the output.